# PrestaShop 1.6 - custom entries in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, caching, prestashop

I need add my custom entry to the .htaccess file. Unfortunately each rebuild of cache or cache refresh in the admin is getting lost my entry. Can I declare that entries in the panel or code to prevent them deleting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using version **1.6.1.1**

Another possibility would be to add your custom entries below the following comment:

```
# ~~end~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again

#Your entries go here e.g
php_value max_input_vars 3000
```

As said in the comment

> Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again

Answer (score 3):

I am using prestashop 1.6.0.6 and i had written my custom .htaccess rules by:
making an override class of Tools.php (located in project_folder/classes/Tools.php)
It has a function:
`generateHtaccess` |search it in Tools.php -> All the things written in .htaccess are generated from here.
If you are playing with .htaccess, deleting cache won't benefit you. You have to generate .htaccess again to see the results. Go to backend: `preference -> SEO & URL -> scroll down to set up urls and click save` | this will generate .htaccess
If you are having cache issues then go to backend:
`Advanced Parameters -> performance -> turn Cache to No | sometimes turning force compilation On also helps` but i would perfer not to do it if you are on production.
Note:
To override Tools.php you have to create new file in `override/classes/Tools.php`, if it doesn't exist. Moreover if you are using `agilemultipleseller` module then you also have to create a copy override file at `modules/agilemultipleseller/override/classes/Tools.php`
whenever you make and override file, make sure to delete `cache/class_index.php` file (don't worry it will be regenerated automatically).
if you need any further help, i would be glad to help you :)